# VBA Macro doesn't save Worksheet with date AND time

Tags: excel, vba, datetime

I have the made the code below that basically saves one sheet of the workbook. First it creates the current year, then the current month, then gives the file todays date and a string that is in Range A1. If the year exists but the month folder doesnt, it then creates only the month folder and saves the sheet. If the file already exists, the sub exits. The sheet works as a daily production review and I want it to work forever (i mean to always save it at the correct folder. The codes works PERFECTLY but now I have a specific problem. There are occasions of 2 reviews during the day, with the same name in the range A1 but are actually 2 different productions so I thought of adding the time also in the filename.

```
Sub savesheet()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim fixedSavePath, yrName, mthName, sheetFileName, mstryr, yearpath, mstrmth, allto As String


fixedSavePath = "C:\Users\jerka\Desktop\Arxeia kapsoulas\"
yrName = Format(Date, "yyyy")
mthName = Format(Date, "mmmm")
sheetFileName = Format(Date, "dd.mm.yyyy") & " " & Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value

mstryr = fixedSavePath & yrName
yearpath = fixedSavePath & yrName & "\"
mstrmth = yearpath & mthName
allto = yearpath & mthName & "\"

fol = Dir(yearpath, vbDirectory)
fal = Dir(allto, vbDirectory)

On Error Resume Next
If fol = "" And fall = "" Then
MkDir mstryr
MkDir mstrmth
ElseIf fol <> "" And fall = "" Then
MkDir mstrmth
End If

strFileName = mstrmth & "\" & sheetFileName & ".xlsx"
strFileExists = Dir(strFileName)
 
If strFileExists <> "" Then
MsgBox "The selected file exists"
Exit Sub
End If
  
Worksheets("Sheet1").Copy
With ActiveWorkbook
.SaveAs Filename:=mstrmth & "\" & sheetFileName & ".xlsx", _
FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, Password:="", WriteResPassword:="", _
ReadOnlyRecommended:=False, CreateBackup:=False
.Close
End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

For some reason that I can't understand, If i write the filename as
VBA Code:

`sheetFileName = Format(Date, "dd.mm.yyyy hh:mm") & " " & Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value`

or in any other way that contains the time, either the "file exists" triggers (even if I delete everything), either it opens a new workbook with the name Book1.xlsx and doesn't save it. Any help will be greatly appreciated cause I really can't wrap my head around this problem

P.S. I have tried the DateTime.Now, putting only the time etc, NOTHING works. Also Format(Datetest, "Long Date") works but "Long Time" doesn't

Comment: You cannot have ":" in file names

Comment: OMG...omg..omg i am stupid....Can't believe i lost 3 hours with this, while I KNOW that file names can't take :...Thanks you so much...If you can write your comment as an answer so I can tag it. Don't know if I should delete it though because is such a stupid mistake.

Comment: Don't worry, everyone of us get lost time to time, feel free to delete it, there's no need to post it as an answer :)

Answer (score 1):

One thing that stands out immediately is that file names cannot contain a colon.
You could try the 24-hour time format HHmm.

Comment: Υeap that was it..Was suggested in the comment by @Sgdva. Was so lost in the cody for the past hours that missed something that I know that doesnt work..But for some reason my brain got stuck..Was thinking of deleting this because its so obvious but I am thinking of leaving it for anyone that gets stuck the same way I did

Comment: Thank you for leaving it.  I got stuck on the damn colon too!